# jupyter-lab does not load jupyter_nbextensions_configurator (but jupyter-notebook does)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Having failed to resolve this after a day and a half of solid effort, I feel I am losing my mind: I have checked config files, rebuilt environments half-a-dozen times, enabled everything possibly relevant, consulted numerous S.O. posts, & github issues and I still can't get it to work.

I want to use certain non-core notebook extensions - and be able to debug using xeus-python  (in an environment set up for TensorFlow with CUDA - this part at least has always been OK)

I have tried numerous combinations of python versions, notebook, conda/pip for installation of jupyter etc. but jupyter-lab will not load jupyter_nbextensions_configurator.

However! I discovered by accident that jupyter-notebook does load it (see line 4) - and suddenly I have something to hang a question on. When I run jupyter-notebook, the output begins...

```
(TF250_PY3810_xeus) A:\My Documents\IT\Programming\Python\Perceptilabs\Batch Files & Shortcuts>jupyter-notebook
[I 10:54:00.733 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\notebook_cookie_secret
[W 10:54:00.992 NotebookApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server will be able to run code.
[I 10:54:01.017 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.4.1
[W 2021-07-01 10:54:01.703 LabApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-07-01 10:54:01.704 LabApp] 'password_required' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-07-01 10:54:01.704 LabApp] 'token' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-07-01 10:54:01.712 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\TF250_PY3810_xeus\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2021-07-01 10:54:01.712 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\TF250_PY3810_xeus\share\jupyter\lab
[I 10:54:01.717 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: A:/My Documents
[I 10:54:01.718 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 10:54:01.718 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 10:54:01.718 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

(Unfortunately, the debugger seems unavailable in jupyter notebook and ipyfilechooser seemed not to work - note that ipyfilechooser *does* work in the same environment under jupyter lab!)

**Question!**
Given this, why isn't jupyter_nbextensions_configurator loaded by jupyter-lab and *how do I fix it?*

I used a specific notebook version in the end but have no idea whether this is in fact important, since the discovery action was not performed before... but I do wonder whether a specific jupyter version might also be required.

(Side issue/bonus question: why are lab & notebook behaviours different in other ways too e.g. debugger, ipyfilechooser?)

**Addtional Info**
System: Win 10, 64-bit

I also tried explicitly using

```
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user/--system/--sys-prefix
```

even if I used the conda installation that should have taken care of this. Obviously to no avail.

The environment in which is created by (silent, no prompts) batch file as follows (most non-functional content stripped out for posting):

```
set envName=TF250_PY3810_xeus
echo Conda stuff - create and activate environment %envName%, add xeus-python and cuda support
call conda create -y --name %envName% python==3.8.10
call C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat %envName%
call conda install -y -c conda-forge xeus-python
call conda install -y -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2.2
call conda install -y -c conda-forge cudnn=8.1.0.77

echo Conda stuff - install jupyterlab, notebook (versioned!), extensions stuff
call conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyterlab notebook==6.1.1
call conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
call conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

@REM pip installations. NB tensorflow_decision_forests is linux only 30/06/2021 so can't install yet
echo Pip stuff - install TensorFlow, seaborn, etc.
pip install -q --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install -q --no-input tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0 tensorflow-probability tensorflow-addons
pip install -q --no-input seaborn tabulate pandoc
pip install -q ipyfilechooser tqdm

@REM Alternative jupyter PIP setup.
@REM pip install -q jupyterlab jupyter_nbextensions_configurator jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 
@REM jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
@REM jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user

@REM jupyter lab
```

Comment: The extension system in `jupyter lab` and `jupyter notebook` are different. While server extensions will generally work for both `nbclassic` (and for some time with `notebook` too) and `jupyterlab`, the `nbextensions_configurator` extension uses the old extension system which is specific to `notebook` and no one ported it to the new extension system.

Comment: What do you want `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` for? Do you want to have equivalent lab extensions to those that that you used for notebook?

Comment: @krassowski - thx! nbextensions_configurator isn't supposed to work with jupyter lab?? <sigh> How did I miss that nugget of critical information (rhetorical). Confusion between "notebook" the thing and "notebook" the framework/... for me. No point trying to achieve the impossible! Thanks. A formal answer saying that (+ maybe a bit more to be useful) would be accepted as The Answer

I wanted collapsible headings in the notebook (thing!) - collapsible TOC is nice but doesn't allow separated things to be visually close together by suitable intermediate collapses.

Comment: Collapsible headings are coming to JupyterLab soon in 3.1 due to be released within a month or so (this function is already merged and available in the beta release - though I would recommend waiting two weeks for RC, or a t least a week for the next beta).

Comment: I will aim to write up an answer on differences between the extension systems later. I do understand why users are sometimes confused, hopefully renaming `notebook` to `nbclassic` could disambiguate this a little bit.

Comment: @krassowski - all good info - thx!

Comment: Here is the link to the PR for collapsing cells via headings in notebooks in JupyterLab:  https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10260 - is this what you want?

Comment: @krassowski Yes, pretty much. Will wait for a full release but looks v. promising (not so keen on seeing "+27 cells" etc. all over the place - a simple collapsed indicator would suffice for me but it would do what I want). Binder no longer working it seems but happy to wait for 3.1 Thx