# Fix jupyter_nbextensions_configurator & jupyter_lsp fail to load?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Related: [jupyter-lab does not load jupyter_nbextensions_configurator (but jupyter-notebook does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208833/jupyter-lab-does-not-load-jupyter-nbextensions-configurator-but-jupyter-noteboo)

This time I didn't request installation of any *jupyter notebook* stuff - did something else drag it in?

The full console output for jupyter lab startup is given below

**Issues**

- jupyter_nbextensions_configurator doesn't load - but it shouldn't be there at all
- jupyter_lsp fails because access denied to .virtual_documents; note that the folder seems to be read only but so is the notebook checkpoint folder beside it, and that works fine (NB Windows controlled access is OFF).

I would like to a) resolve the existing issues and b) prevent them from occurring again

I have tried removing/disabling references to jupyter_nbextensions_configurator where I could find them, but to no avail: I guess I have not found (all?) the right places.

**Background**

After creation of the basic environment with Conda, I use pip *exclusively* (except to install nVidia CUDA stuff from Conda), and my pip installs for the environment are:

```
pip install -q --upgrade pip setuptools pip-autoremove
pip install --no-input numpy==1.23.* numba matplotlib cupy-cuda112 pandas pandoc plotly scipy seaborn statistics tabulate line_profiler
pip install --no-input tensorflow==2.9.1 tensorflow-probability tensorflow-addons tensorflow_datasets tensorflow-text==2.9.0 
pip install --no-input pywebcopy bs4 PySimpleGUI display_xml gtts playsound
pip install --no-input jupyterlab ipyfilechooser tqdm wget
pip install -q jupyterlab-lsp python-lsp-server[all]
```

When I start jupyter lab I get this:

**Console output**

```
(PYTFCurrent) c:\Users\Julian>jupyter lab
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:48.320 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:48.335 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.341 NotebookApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.341 NotebookApp] 'password_required' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.341 NotebookApp] 'token' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.348 ServerApp] notebook_dir is deprecated, use root_dir
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:48.348 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.756 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | error adding extension (enabled: True): The module 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator' could not be found (No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 175, in _validate_name
        self._module, self._metadata = get_metadata(name)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\utils.py", line 55, in get_metadata
        module = importlib.import_module(package_name)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 320, in add_extension
        extpkg = ExtensionPackage(name=extension_name, enabled=enabled)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 166, in __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1232, in __init__        with self.hold_trait_notifications():
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\contextlib.py", line 142, in __exit__
        next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1348, in hold_trait_notifications
        value = trait._cross_validate(self, getattr(self, name))
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 729, in _cross_validate
        value = obj._trait_validators[self.name](obj, proposal)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1132, in __call__        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 177, in _validate_name
        raise ExtensionModuleNotFound(
    jupyter_server.extension.utils.ExtensionModuleNotFound: The module 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator' could not be found (No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:48.759 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:48.799 ServerApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server will be able to run code.
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:48.805 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.280 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[W 2022-11-10 15:31:49.892 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension failed loading with message: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'a:\\My Documents\\.virtual_documents'
[E 2022-11-10 15:31:49.893 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | stack trace
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 355, in load_extension
        extension.load_all_points(self.serverapp)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 229, in load_all_points
        return [self.load_point(point_name, serverapp) for point_name in self.extension_points]
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 229, in <listcomp>
        return [self.load_point(point_name, serverapp) for point_name in self.extension_points]
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 222, in load_point
        return point.load(serverapp)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 148, in load
        return loader(serverapp)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_lsp\serverextension.py", line 50, in load_jupyter_server_extension
        setup_shadow_filesystem(virtual_documents_uri=virtual_documents_uri)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyter_lsp\virtual_documents_shadow.py", line 116, in setup_shadow_filesystem
        rmtree(str(shadow_filesystem))
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\shutil.py", line 749, in rmtree
        return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\shutil.py", line 623, in _rmtree_unsafe
        onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
      File "C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\shutil.py", line 621, in _rmtree_unsafe
        os.rmdir(path)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'a:\\My Documents\\.virtual_documents'
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.896 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.896 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.901 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.909 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.910 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: A:\My Documents
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.910 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.23.1 is running at:
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.910 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.910 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:49.910 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 2022-11-10 15:31:55.760 LabApp] Build is up to date
```

**Installation Info**

Python 3.10.6, Windows 10

```
(PYTFCurrent) c:\Users\Julian>conda list jupyter*
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\PYTFCurrent:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter-client            7.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-lsp               1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            1.23.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab                3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-lsp            3.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
```

PS Advice on actioning "This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release." would not be unwelcome either.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will be superseded by a better one, explaining why the situation arose, however I discovered that the json config files that needed to be edited are in fact at:

```
C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

(found by running `!jupyter server extension list` in a notebook cell)

where jupyter_notebook_config.json is to be found, and maybe in the nbconfig subfolder too (tree.json, notebook.json) where I removed lines referring to nbextensions_configurator etc.

I don't know why there are similar files in `C:\Users\Julian\.jupyter` but editing them had no effect.

There is now no configurator error and jupyer_lsp also loads correctly.